# How to add validation to @Input in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, validation

How can you add validation to `@Input` in angular so that angular throws an error when you provide an `@Input` that is not in the options you provided. I tried using enums, but enums can not validate variables from the template.

My current working implementation is using if statements. For example:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'dropdown',
  templateUrl: './dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dropdown.component.scss']
})
export class DropdownComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() option;
  validOptions = ['option1','option2','option3','option4','option5'];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.validateOptionInput()
  }

  validateOptionInput(){
    this.validOptions.forEach(myFunction);

    function myFunction(value) {
      if((this.validOptions != value){
        throw({error: `${value} is not a valid input variable. The valid options are: ${this.validOptions}`})
      } else {
        return;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Is there a way to do the same using enums or a way built in, in angular?

Comment: You should not validate only in `OnInit` hook, `option` is an Input, therefore, its value can be later

Comment: Do you mean like this?? https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-angular-starter-woejls

Comment: Also there are some modifications needs to be done in this line, ```if((this.validOptions =! value)``` .. which needs to be like ```if(this.validOptions != value)```

Comment: @ManirajMurugan yes like that. My code works, I was looking for an alternative that uses less code and maybe inbuilt in angular.

Comment: @htn Your comment is really useful. I think it should be part of your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enum is only a set of constants. If you want to add validation ==> it have to be done in runtime, such as:

```
const validOptions = ['option1','option2','option3','option4','option5'];
export class DropdownComponent {
  @Input() set option(v: any) {
     if (validOptions.includes(v)) {
        this._option = v;
     } else {
        // handle error
     }
  }
  get option(): any {
     return option;
  }
  private _option: any;
}
```

You may as well use some validation library, but it's still heavy. I would prefer working with types and using angular compilation `strictTemplates` option often to detect wrong type assignment.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know Angular can only help with with making that Input mandatory using the annotation **@isRequired**.

As about the verification of the input value I think it is okay to manually check it but I strongly recommend to use it in the **ngOnChanges** Angular Life Hook. That method is triggered everytime one of your @Input values are changing and you would want to make that check everytime that happens.

Comment: Slightly disagree with ngOnChanges Life Hook. What about adding Form Validation. https://angular.io/guide/form-validation